# USB boot with no windows?

Tags: boot, usb

I fried my computer trying to load Alpine Linux.   Now I can't do anything.

I have Ubuntu. iso on a USB, is that all I need?

How do I run it from BOOT: prompt?

I think I formatted my drive and deleted my Windows Recovery disc too!

Answer (score 0):

Simply placing the .iso on the USB drive is not enough. If you intend on booting from USB you will need to do two things - you will need to change your BIOS settings to allow booting from USB and you will need to make the drive bootable. If you have another computer available I suggest using [UNetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to create a bootable USB drive with your preferred flavor of Linux

Comment: if he has a compatible boot loader, all he will need is an iso file. I dont remember how, but it is possible to boot into the iso directly. Anyways, unetbootin is a better option.